# What is the good practice to create modal for nested objects using angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript

what is the best way to create a modal for nested objects for body payload of post API using angular8

```
{​​​​​​​
  "Reason": "Test",
  "address": "abcd",
  "nested address": {​​​​​​​
    "id": 012,
    "name": "testname"
  }​​​​​​​,
  "contact": {​​​​​​​
    "id": 1001,
    "name": "contactname"
  }​​​​​​​,
  "numbers": 111,
  "price": 10000,
  "group": {​​​​​​​
    "id": 00,
    "title": "string"
  }​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
}​​​​​​​
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your question, what do you mean by "create a modal for nested objects for body payload of post API"

Answer (score 0):

And I have found it in this way, we can created a nested class and add type to it,

```
contact.ts
```

```
export class CreateOrder {
  public Reason: string;
  public address: string;
  public nestedAddress: NestedAddress;
  public contact: Contact;
}

export class NestedAddress{
   id:number;
   string:string
}

export class Contact {
   id:number;
   string:number
}
```